# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer

Tags: java, asp.net, android-studio, https, ksoap2

I have an Android application that consumes ASP.Net web services.

It does not work from Android 7, generating the following error:

**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer**

The summary code is:

```
AllCertificatesAndHostsTruster.apply ();
HttpsTransportSE transport = new KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE (context.getResources (). GetString (R.string.server_local), 443, URL, timeoutGlobal);
transport.call (SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Source of AllCertificatesAndHostsTruster.apply (): https://gist.github.com/gotev/6784c1303793c6ee9e56

Any ideas? Thanks since now.

Comment: Under Android 6 and less version, it can works well?

Comment: Yes, problem from Android 7

Comment: Sorry for long delay.. if possible, can you please compare Root trusted CA list in android 6.0 and android 7.0, follow steps:
1. Open Settings
2. Tap “Security & location”
3. Tap “Encryption & credentials”
4. Tap “Trusted credentials.” This will display a list of all trusted certs on the device.

I see you just overided hostname verification, hm..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set TLS enabled from the server side.

Comment: Can you provide some help to check that? It is Window Server 2003 with ASP.Net. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

JVM argument to enable TLSv1.2 if your certificate on the server doesn't support TLS1 (which is the java 7 default)

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https